# Python asyncio web scraping output not exporting in excel

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, event-loop

I'am new to Python asyncio web scraping. I want to export scraped data to excel using pandas. Seems like my code bellow is scraping target fields but while I am exporting output using pandas to excel then I am getting empty output file.

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

input_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Sample.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(input_file, usecols=0)

req = requests.Session()
req.trust_env = False

Url, title, price = [], [], [],
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)


def scrape(url, *, loop):
    loop.run_in_executor(executor, load_html, url)


def load_html(url):
    print(url)
    res = req.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
    Url.append(url)
    title.append(soup.select('.pinfo-title')[0].text)
    price.append(soup.select('.sale-price')[0].text)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
for url in df['Urls']:
    scrape(url, loop=loop)

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*asyncio.all_tasks(loop)))

output = pd.DataFrame({
        'Url': Url,
        'Title': title,
        'Price': price
})
output.to_excel('Output.xlsx', index=False)
```

but If i use print instead of appending lists like bellow, then it's print desired output.

```
def load_html(url):
    print(url)
    res = req.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
    print(url)
    print(soup.select('.pinfo-title')[0].text)
    print(soup.select('.sale-price')[0].text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `run_in_executor` does not add a Task to the loop. It has to be awaited. So you need to wrap it in a co-routine and create a task in the loop. Simpler example below.

```
import asyncio
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

URLS = [
    "http://localhost:8000/a",
    "http://localhost:8000/b",
    "http://localhost:8000/c",
    "http://localhost:8000/d",
]

data = []


def load_html(url):
    print(url)
    res = urlopen(url)
    data.append(res.read().decode())


async def scrape(url, loop):
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, load_html, url)


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for url in URLS:
        loop.create_task(scrape(url, loop))

    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*asyncio.all_tasks(loop)))
    with open('/tmp/j_dump', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Update:**

Code can be simplified as below. No need extra co-routines or global data.

```
def load_html(url):
    print(url)
    res = urlopen(url)
    return res.read().decode()


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(None, load_html, url) for url in URLS]
    data = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    with open('/tmp/j_dump', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)
```